# Joining 2 tables with non-key columns in JPA, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I am working with a legacy DB with tables `skl_transactions` and `merchant_config`. These two tables have a column where their values are equivalent to each other (e.g. `skl_transactions.column_a` === `merchant_config.column.b` . I am looking at a way to join both tables base on that common value instead of querying the DB twice.

See what I came up with but I keep having an error

```
(" => "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: column_a in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(merchant_config) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: column_a in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(merchant_config) and its related supertables and secondary tables"}}
```

Below is my Entity class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "skl_transactions")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "column_a")
    private String senderAddress;

    -----

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="column_b", referencedColumnName = "column_a")
    private Bar merchant;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "merchant_config")
public class Bar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "column_b")
    private String merchantAddress;

    -----

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant_config", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Foo> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

NB: Both columns are not marked as primary or foreign keys.

What I am looking for is when I query a transaction from `skl_transactions` table, it will join the merchant that has that transaction from the `merchant_config` table.

Comment: Well for start I think you have the name and referencedColumnName the other way round. Try : `@JoinColumn(name="column_a", referencedColumnName = "column_b")`

Comment: @pleft thanks a lot. I got the below error trying to redeploy after making the changes as you suggested.

`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Foo.merchant_config in Bar.transactions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `mappedBy` to `merchant`

**Foo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skl_transactions")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "column_a")
    private String senderAddress;

    -----

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="column_b", referencedColumnName = "column_a", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Bar merchant;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Bar**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "merchant_config")
public class Bar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "column_b")
    private String merchantAddress;

    -----

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Foo> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

If above have any issue try changing `name` and `referencedColumnName` the other way round

```
in Foo
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="column_a", referencedColumnName = "column_b", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Bar merchant;

in Bar
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Foo> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Made the changes and got the below: 
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Foo column: column_a (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\"`

Comment: @Emmajiugo Yes you need to add the `insertable=false, updatable=false` to `@JoinColumn` in `Foo`. Updated the answer.